# How does correlation and conditional probability relate?

Tags: probability, correlation

Suppose we have two random variables $p \in [0,1]$ and $q \in [0,1]$ with correlation $\rho$. My question: knowing $\rho$, how do I update my probability distribution over values of one of the variables, when I learn the value of the other?

As an example, suppose that $\rho = 0.5$, and I learn that $p=1$. What can I say about the *expected value* $q$? If I'm maximizing accuracy, what value should I predict? Plausibly, if the expected value of $q$ was $0.5$ before (perhaps by the principle of insufficient reason) then I should adjust this upwards when I learn of the correlation and value of $p$. But in what way, and how much exactly?

I think I'm confused about how correlation relates to probabilities and Bayesian updating. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[q | p]$ depends on the joint probability distribution between $p$ and $q$. Do you have any further information on this?

Comment: @fesman, hm, this is all I know. It just seems that I should be able to say _something_. But perhaps not then.

Comment: You could do some linear projection $E(q|p)\approx E(q)+(p-E(p))\times \frac{Cov(p,q)}{Var(p)}$. But it is just a crude approximation (exact with multivariate normal distribution).

Comment: Thanks, @fesman!